# How to calculate Pi using Monte Carlo Simulation?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to write a FORTRAN 90 program that calculates Pi using random numbers. These are the steps I know I need to undertake:

1. Create a randomly placed point on a 2D surface within the range [−1, 1] for x and y, using call random_number(x).
2. calculate how far away the point is from the origin, i'll need to do both of these steps for N points.
3. for each N value work out the total amount of points that are less than 1 away from origin. Calculate pi with A=4pir^2
4. use a do loop to calculate pi as a function of N and output it to a data file. then plot it in a graphing package.

This is what I have:

```
program pi 
implicit none

integer :: count, n, i
real :: r, x, y
count = 0

CALL RANDOM_SEED
DO i = 1, n
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(y)
 IF (x*x + y*Y <1.0) count = count + 1
END DO
r = 4 * REAL(count)/n
print *, r
end program pi
```

I know i've missed out printing the results to the data file, i'm not sure on how to implement this.

This program gives me a nice value for pi (3.149..), but how can I implement step 4, so that it outputs values for pi as a function of N?

Thanks.

Comment: Any loop, but more likely normal do loop. It depends on which values of n you want to compute.

Comment: @VladimirF So say I wanted to print a corresponding value for pi to n, using n = 10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000. Would I just use a loop around my original loop: do n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000? How would I input this into my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the final calculation step inside the outer loop, and replace `n` with `i`. Also maybe add a condition to limit the number of results printed, e.g. `i % 100 = 0` to print every 100 iterations.

```
program pi 
implicit none

integer :: count, n, i
real :: r, x, y
count = 0

CALL RANDOM_SEED

DO i = 1, n
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(y)
 IF (x*x + y*Y <1.0) count = count + 1

 IF ([condition])
   r = 4 * REAL(count)/i
   print *, i, r
 END IF
END DO

end program pi
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do you suggest I use as the condition?

Comment: @timetabedlidalot I put an example in the answer as `i % 100 == 0`, but you can use any. The purpose of this is to reduce the number of output data points for when you need large `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to further @meowgoesthedog effort...

```
Program pi 
implicit none

integer :: count, n, i
real :: r, x, y
count = 0
Integer, parameter :: Slice_o_Pie = 8
Integer :: Don_McLean
Logical :: Purr = .FALSE.

OPEN(NEWUNIT=Don_McLean, FILE='American.Pie')
CALL RANDOM_SEED

DO i = 1, n
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(y)
  IF (x*x + y*Y <1.0) count = count + 1

  Purr = .FALSE.
  IF(MODULO(I, Slice_o_Pie) == 0) Purr = .TRUE.

  IF (Purr) THEN
    r = 4 * REAL(count)/i
    print *, i, r
    WRITE(LUN,*) 'I=',I,'Pi=',Pi
  END IF
END DO

CLOSE(Don_McLean)
end program pi
```